# how to view json file data in view source code

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Let suppose i have a json file

and i can read this file in my script like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "Package.html",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 var t = '';


                 for (var i = 0; i < data.yearData.length; i++) {



                     var mainStoryTitle = data.yearData[i].players;
                     for (var j = 0; j < mainStoryTitle.length; j++) {
                         var storyTitle = mainStoryTitle[j].name;
                         var topStoryContent = mainStoryTitle[j].description;
                         var storyImage = mainStoryTitle[j].image;
                         t = t + '<div class="content">';
                         t = t + '<article class="topcontent">';
                         t = t + '<header class="top" id="top1"><h2>' + storyTitle + '</h2></header>';
                         t = t + '<header class="bottom">';
                         t = t + '<h6><img src="' + storyImage + '" height=150 width=200>' + '</h6></header>';
                         t = t + '<content class="hide" id="content_' + j + '"><p>' + topStoryContent + '</p></content>';
                         t = t + '</article>';
                         t = t + '</div>';
                         }

                 }


                 $(".content").html(t);

             },
             error: function (e, ts, et) { alert(ts) }

         })
     });
```

and then i put this script in my html file.
So when i run this, it works properly but the problem is when i click on view source then inside it shows the path of json instead of exact data.
Hope you got the problem and please revert me asap.thanx

Comment: That is because JavaScript only changes the DOM, not the actual source. Why would you want that anyway?

Comment: Short answer, you can't (it's not source, it's a resource - regardless of the contained content). Longer answer, put a breakpoint on `var t = '';` if you'd like to see the data as loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using alert, use console.log(ts) this will post the JSON file into your console. From there you can easily look around and see the JSON file by clicking the down arrow.

```
console.log(data); shows as:
> Object {Data: Array[2], ResponseMessage: "", Success: true}


console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); shows as:
{"Data":[{"ControllerID":2,"Description":"Aeon Power Monitor","DevType":1,"ID":1,"Name":"Power Monitor"},{"ControllerID":2,"Description":"Aeon Power Switch","DevType":2,"ID":2,"Name":"Switch"}],"ResponseMessage":"","Success":true}
```

[image: JSON View Log]